# Angular - How can I write a condition in interpolation?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-ngmodel

I have a table which is being populated through the `add client` form. It works fine and the changes are displayed. The thing is I have a select list in which a user selects the specific source and then it is saved in ngmodel. Here is the code.

**Select List**

```
 <mat-select [(ngModel)]="model.source" name="source" placeholder="Select Source ">
      <mat-option [value]="1 ">Upwork</mat-option>
      <mat-option [value]="2 ">Refer from Friend</mat-option>
      <mat-option [value]="3 ">Other</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
```

Now in my table the value which displays is 1 or 2 or 3 based on the selection. I want to write something, a condition in interpolation like this.

**Table Field**

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="source">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Source </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.source ? if value is 1 : display (upwork), if value is 2 : display(refer from friend)}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Some thing like this, I did like it in `angularjs` I am not sure about Angular

Comment: Did you look at the examples in the template syntax docs? E.g. https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#style-binding shows a ternary conditional expression, or you could use `ngSwitch` to replace the whole element.

Comment: @jonrsharpe man i cant see interpolation here, its just property bining

Comment: The syntax is consistent throughout the template. For anything non-trivial, though, it might be better to write the logic in the class and just interpolate the resulting *value* in the template. Otherwise the template becomes very hard to read.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can use nested ternary if

```
{{element.source == 1 ? 'upwork' : (element.source == 2 ? 'refer from friend' : '')}}
```

or probably better

```
export class MyComponent {
  sourceNames = {1: 'upwork', 2: 'refer from friend', 3: 'other' };
}
```

```
{{sourceNames[element.source]}}
```

Comment: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token : at column 24 in [{{element.source === 1 ? : 'upwork' : (element.source === 2 ? 'refer from friend' : '')}}
      ] in ng:///AppModule/ClientsComponent.html@53:42 ("header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Source </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">[ERROR ->]{{element.source === 1 ? : 'upwork' : (element.source === 2 ? 'refer from friend' : '')}}
      </ma"): ng:///AppModule/ClientsComponent.html@53:42

Comment: Please update your question and add the code that that causes the error message and the error message. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: There was a redundant `:`. I removed it in my answer.

Comment: what about the third condition, will it be like this ?                 
                {{element.source === 1 ? 'upwork' : (element.source === 2 ? 'refer from friend' : ' ' : (element.source === 3 ? ' other'  : ' ' ) ) } }

Comment: Just use `'other'` instead of `''` with the code of my answer. I'll also add a better answer.

Comment: The fist option may not work due to the fact that value can be string. `element.source == 1` should do the trick

Comment: Good catch `[value]="1 "` with the space after the number. With `==` instead of `===` it should work right?

Comment: Seems even with `[value]="1"` angular will set `string` to model https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f212bc?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Right, I assumed `[ngValue]`. My Angular  + TS knowledge is becoming rusty :'-/

Comment: How is your mobile development?)

Comment: Even worse :D Haven't done any mobile development before. But it is with [Flutter](https://flutter.io/) which uses Dart which makes me happy ;-).

Comment: Angular 7: [matTooltip]="GridToolTip[index]"  worked for me! instead

Comment: The nested method is great!! I found it more helpful when writing conditions I HTML only. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

@Günter Zöchbauer answer works perfectly. Here i have used the same and did a little modification.

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="cards.length != 0">
          <div class="cards-descriptor__title noResults">
            <p>
              {{ cards.length }}
              {{cards.length > 1 ? generalAppSettings.filterVariables.filterResultsTextMultiple
                  : generalAppSettings.filterVariables.filterResultsTextSingle
              }}
            </p>
          </div>
        </ng-container>
```

Single Entry
[image]

Multiple Entries
[image]